# Changes in query behaviour

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some queries that run every day for several month with no problem. I didn't change anything in the queries for a long while.
In the past few days some of them fail. Error message says something regarding some fields: "Field 'myfield' not found.". these queries usually involve some sub-queries and window functions.
Example for the BQ guys:

- On 2015-08-03 Job ID: job_EUWyK5DIFSxJxGAEC4En2Q_hNO8 run successfully
- on the following days, same query, failed. Job IDs: (job_A9KYJLbQJQvHjh1g7Fc0Abd2qsc , job__15ff66aYseR-YjYnPqWmSJ30N8)

In addition, for some other queries running times extended from minutes to hours and sometime return "timeout".

My questions:

1. Was something changed in the BQ engine?
2. What should I do to make my queries run again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the problem could be two folded:

1. An update to query execution engine was rolled out during the week of August 3, 2015 as documented in the [announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bigquery-announce/i6w9HwybW4E)

If this is the case, you need to update your queries.

2. Some performance issues were detected lately, but in order to actually identify if there is something wrong with your project or not, you need to [create a issue request](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/) I did the same [in past](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=283&sort=-id) and it was fixed.

Comment: Thank you... 1. There was nothing mentioned regarding this change in the release notes (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/release-notes?hl=en). 2. can someone explain what impact this change should have on performance (query run times)?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=299 for performance issues. We've rolled out an update that we believe will address these performance issues, but please let us know if they persist. Feel free to open a new bug with job IDs for slow queries if you see new ones.